# OpenAL - alGetSourcei and AL_BUFFERS_PROCESSED gives junk

Tags: c++, software-engineering, openal

Posted this question on SO but got no answers. Maybe somebody can help me here.

I recently had a well-working program which streamed WAV and Ogg sounds with OpenAL. I then decided to abstract the source and buffer objects into C++ classes. I got as far as the source class. My function which returns the number of processed buffers is not altering the integer passed to `alGetSourcei`.

```
int ALSource::GetBuffersProcessed() const {
    ALint processed;
    alGetSourcei(this->source, AL_BUFFERS_PROCESSED, &processed);
    int error = alGetError();
    if(error != AL_NO_ERROR)
            return -1;
    return processed;
}
```

I checked that `error` is never anything but `AL_NO_ERROR`. I generate the source in the 
constructor:

```
alGenSources(1, &source);
```

This also never gives any error.

The actual symptom of this is that `processed` is declared but not initialised. It's final value is the initial junk value that it starts out with. (Usually something like -8834824334).

Would this be expected behaviour? The OpenAL specification states that the value should be from `0 - any` but is not really any more specific than that. The programmers' guide is the same.

Comment: I had to read this twice to figure out what you were asking.  
Consider reworking the question to make this more obvious.

Comment: @caspin, what parts are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here goes the solution. The root cause was an implicit destructor call which destroyed my AL context. What's interesting is that a bug in the Windows implementation causes OpenAL to fail silently when there is no current context. So all my calls to `alGetError` returned `AL_NO_ERROR` because there was no context. It's a nasty little bug, in my opinion.